# Custom Design in IPhone Applications

Tags: iphone

I want to create the following design to my IPhone application.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the following tutorial on Vimeo by [SkyTrix](http://twitter.com/skytrix), which exactly shows what you're trying to achieve.

Link: [Tutorial on SMS style bubbles](http://vimeo.com/8718829)